Booting to black screen on battery power
I have recently setup a laptop with Ubuntu 24.04, this is Dell Latitude 5591 with Nvidia GPU (geforce mx130) and an Intel iGPU. When I boot the laptop on battery power it simply boots to a black screen with no way to do anything, it seems the kernel hangs. The strange thing is that this only happens on battery power, when plugged in the laptop boots perfectly fine. Prior to installing Ubuntu the laptop was running windows and would boot on a battery just fine. I suspect issue with GPU on battery power, but have no evidence for it, journactl -fk does not have anything GPU related. I have tried to different kernels as well as switching to Ubuntu 22.04 with the same results. The issue is quite annoying as it beats the purpose of being a laptop. The nvidia prime-select is set to on-demand. Also setting nomodeset as suggested around the interwebs does not change the situation.
I am very thankful for further ideas, perhaps something to look for in journal?
Thank you!

Was resolved by a bios update.
